# Django runserver throwing OSError: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, linux, django, debian, virtualenv

Everything in my Django Development server setup as virtual environment was working fine until recently when I start development server the following error occurred. Can anyone suggest the solution or point to any specific issue?

```
    (iwidget)adeel@iwidget:~/python_virtual/django_project/iwidget_consumer$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8006
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 79, in handle
    self.run(*args, **options)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 181, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 153, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 140, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 573, in spawnve
    return _spawnvef(mode, file, args, env, execve)
  File "/home/adeel/python_virtual/iwidget/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 531, in _spawnvef
    pid = fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: But you do have enough free RAM/HDD?

Comment: Definitely no issue with the RAM and HDD. Server health is 100%.

Comment: I just ran up against the same thing. Adeei, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Enough RAM and HDD. Never found any solution :(